# Why does this code work with if statement but not while loop?

Tags: java, if-statement, interface, while-loop, hardware-interface

```
public void timerCallback()
{
    if (count < 8)
    {
        System.out.println("My timer woke up!");
        this.setOutputState(this.pinNumber, this.pinState);
        this.pinState = !this.pinState;
        this.setTimer(this.timerDelay);
        count++;
    }else
     {
        this.stopMonitoring();
     }
}
```

That works in the sense that it prints the statement (with the delay) 8 times then terminates the program. Now this:

```
public void timerCallback()
{
    while (count < 8)
    {
        System.out.println("My timer woke up!");
        this.setOutputState(this.pinNumber, this.pinState);
        this.pinState = !this.pinState;
        this.setTimer(this.timerDelay);
        count++;
    } 
        this.stopMonitoring();
}
```

That code just prints the statement 8 times at once, then terminates. Why is that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java : Recursion -While Loop Vs If Loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11840294/java-recursion-while-loop-vs-if-loop)

Comment: Your first example requires that `timerCallback()` be called for *each* output of "My timer woke up!", whereas your second example does it all within a loop inside of *one* call to `timerCallback()`. `while` will continue to re-execute the following statement or block until the condition fails. `if` only executes the block once if the condition is true.

Comment: You'll want to know the difference between `if` and `while`...

Comment: Here's a hint... when is `timerCallback()` called? It looks like you want it called 8 times before you `stopMonitoring()`, so what makes it get called 8 times?

Comment: NOT A DUP of the recursion question. This question is all about triggering a callback. There's no recursion here. (Although it does bear some resemblance due to the `while`/`if` confusion...)

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the `if/else` in the original version is to give the timer eight chances to "wake up" and toggle pin state before invoking `stopMonitoring()`. Printing the message is secondary. So the `if/else` checks to see if `timerCallback()` has been called 8 times. If it hasn't, ok, print the message and give it another chance.

By substituting a `while`, you just end up printing the message 8 times, toggling pin state back and forth rapidly without checking to see if it helps, and then dropping into `stopMonitoring()`. So you stop monitoring after the first call to `timerCallback()`, not the eighth.